# Windows 7 to make all explorer views Detailed

Tags: windows-7

Although I opened explorer, set it to detailed and from options clicked **Apply to All Folders**, some folders still show up in **Large Icon** mode. To my understanding those are folders with media files? How to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer myself

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"
```

did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because each folder's settings save individually, and applying to all folders only applies to those who don't have settings already. Try use the "Reset Folders" buttons first, then applying the current view to all folders.

Comment: Tried to reset, but...nop, even not explored folders containing media files showing up as Large Icons.